# Angular / rxjs observable function returning without the HTTP data

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0

I have a function to return a fresh access token from a remote server using a refresh token (to be used with HttpInterceptor in Angular 4.3+), based on this [Angular 4 Tutorial - Handling Refresh Token with New HttpInterceptor](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-handling-refresh-token-with-new-httpinterceptor/):

```
doRefreshToken(): Observable<string> {
   http.post('/my/api', refreshToken)
        .subscribe(
          (data) => {
            this.newAccessToken = (<any>data).accessToken;
            console.log("RECEIVED NEW TOKEN: " + this.newAccessToken);
          }, 
          (error) => { },
          () => { }
         );
    console.log("RETURNING NEW TOKEN: " + this.newAccessToken); 
    return Observable.of(this.newAccessToken);
}
```

But calling `doRefreshToken()` returns `undefined` before a token is received from the server.  Why is the function responding before the data arrives?

The console output:

`RETURNING NEW TOKEN: undefined
blah blah blah
RECEIVED NEW TOKEN: abc123imanewtoken`

Comment: Because `http.post` is asynchronous. You should return the result of `http.post`, which is an Observable anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http.post` is not synchronous. You should use something like this instead:

```
doRefreshToken(): Observable<string> {
   return new Observable<string>((observer) => {
      http.post('/my/api', refreshToken)
        .subscribe(
          (data) => {
            if (data && data.accessToken) {
              observer.next((<any>data).accessToken);
            } else {
              observer.error();
            }
          }, 
          (error) => { observer.error(); },
          () => { }
         );
   });
}
```